# Are there any recurring South Park characters who do not appear in Stick of Truth?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

Stick of Truth did a great job at fitting a huge amount of memorable characters from 17 seasons of South Park into a single video game. But didn't they forget someone?

Is there any recurring South Park character who does not appear at all in Stick of Truth?

I would consider any character as "recurring" who has a speaking role in more than one South Park episode.

As "appearance in the game" I would count any on-screen depiction - be it in form of an actual character or just a still picture, the character not appearing on-screen but having a spoken line, or the character being mentioned by name in dialog or text.

Comment: From the top of my head I don't remember if santa was in the game?! Also Pip?

Comment: Santa was in the game. Iirc, he can be found on top of the police station.

Comment: I don't remember seeing Big Gay Al other than a certain section involving Mr Slave.  Starvin' Marvin was also not there, though he is a very old character.

Comment: @MattR I also think Big Gay Al is mentioned by Mr. Slave in some off-hand comment, so he does appear according to the definition in the question. But [Starvin Marvin](http://southpark.wikia.com/wiki/Starvin%27_Marvin_%28character%29) could indeed be missing.

Comment: Big Gay Al appears somewhat indirectly and can be added to your friends list, very close to the end of the game.

Comment: There's a nice list of characters who just mentioned in the game (with not physical appearence) [here](http://spsot.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Mentioned_Characters)